# ObjetBox one to one relations

Tags: objectbox

Models A and B each has a ToOne relation targeting the other.  Do I have to setTarget on both sides, or is it OK just to set on one side, as with many to many?

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes a ToOne relation is saved by setting a virtual target ID property on an object. Also a ToOne relation is unidirectional. So the two ToOne relations are independent.

Maybe instead using a backlink works for you. If each A refers to a different B, a backlink to that ToOne relation will only contain a single A. E.g.:

```
// In A
ToOne<B> relationToB;

// In B
@Backlink(to = "relationToB")
ToMany<A> relationToA;
```

Sources:

- https://docs.objectbox.io/relations#how-toone-works-behind-the-scenes
- https://docs.objectbox.io/relations#one-to-many-1-n